# How to connect localhost to Android studio web view

Tags: php, android, webview, xampp, localhost

I want to add a fully ready PHP website (which is integrated with XAMPP server) in my Android webview project .i can run that PHP website using XAMPP running on my same machine. But how to add this localhost into my webview android project.  Please help me.

Comment: What is the problem with using WebView.loadUrl()?

Comment: And what is the url used in a browser on the pc? Or used with a browser on your Android device which is in the same local net?

Comment: what is url of your website ? is it working with localhost ?

Answer (score 0):

Android WebView connect with localhost

- Allow internet permission
- Use android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in application tag
- Use `http://10.0.2.2/pagename` or `http://your_ip:8080/index.html`

  ```
  webView.loadUrl("http://10.0.2.2/index.html")
    webView.settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE
    webView.settings.setAppCacheEnabled(false)
  ```